# RabbitMQ consume most recent message

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a real-time RabbitMQ queue that I'm running. I'd like to consume the most recent entry, ignoring all others.

Better yet, is it possible to have a fanout exchange with a singleton queue size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by specifying the maximum queue length limit when declaring the queue.

As the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) states,

> The maximum length of a queue can be limited to a set number of messages, or a set number of bytes (the total of all message body lengths, ignoring message properties and any overheads), or both.
>
> The default behaviour for RabbitMQ when a maximum queue length or size is set and the maximum is reached is to drop or dead-letter messages from the front of the queue (i.e. the oldest messages in the queue). To modify this behaviour, use the overflow setting described below.

If you're using Java, you would do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-max-length", 1);
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```